# How to mount cell phone by USB as SCSI block device?

Tags: usb, mount, mobile-phone

A Motorola RIZR Z3 is connected by USB to my desktop machine running XUbuntu (or Ubuntu with xfce tacked on later) with the goal of viewing the phone's file system, copy images back and forth, etc.

The phone has a menu option to choose between Data Connection or Memory Card.  The latter is probably what I want. In this case, the phone shows as a USB class 8 device (mass storage), and a new scsi block device appears, let's call it /dev/sdx (not really 'x'; I don't have *that* many disks) but no partitions like /dev/sdx1.  Attempts to mount it fail.

I read that sometimes when no partitions appear, fdisk -l /dev/sdx (that's lower case ell) will fix it.  Not here.  fdisk says "No medium found."

Other findings from googling haven't helped. Special software for dealing with mobile phones include moto4lin, which appears to be obsolete and gone, and wammu which by my experimentation only works with Data Connection mode (phone appears as character device /dev/ttyACM0 (?), no scsi device).

All hardware and cable are established good.

How do mount this partitionless /dev/sdx or otherwise get access by USB to the files on this phone?

Comment: Some phones wont show the internal storage as block device, they just show the memory card you have put in your phone. If phone does not have a memory card plugged in it might give the 'No medium found' error.

Comment: Discovered something called p2kcommander that does what I want, at least for now.  Described best at http://fondfire.blogspot.com/2009/04/p2k-commander-for-ubuntu.html with links to Ubuntu-compatible .deb files, and source.  Whew!